# how can i miscellaneously fetch data from two tables?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am working on a question- answer site in laravel , my site manages questions view as https://in.pinterest.com site with scroll pagination. i have managed my questions in "questions" table . now i want to introduce new feature "Challenges" and i want to miscellaneously display both "questions" and "Challenges". i need to do it in single loop. how can i do that?

my current laravel query builder logic is:

```
$questions = DB::table('questions')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: the display fields are different for questions and challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not do it with a database query but i did with following.

```
<?php 
    $challenge_count=count($challenges);
    $idea_count=count($cards);
    $loopCounter=($idea_count>$challenge_count)?$idea_count:$challenge_count;
?>
<section class="cards container-fluid">
    <!-- mixed display of challenges and cards-->
    <?php for($i=0;$i<$loopCounter;$i++):?>
        <?php if (array_key_exists($i, $challenges)):
            $challenge=$challenges[$i];?>
            @include('partials.challenge')
        <?php endif; ?>    

        <?php if (array_key_exists($i, $cards)):
            $card=$cards[$i];?>
            @include('partials.card')
        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endfor;?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are pretty free to do as you wish. Not knowing enough of the structure that you're using by reading your question I would suggest some solutions.

1) If the structure are similar for your questions/challenges. You can create a view directly into the DB and merge them together by using: JOIN (sql query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

2) You can get both table into a single transaction and merge it on the server side. This is a bit less efficient but still viable depending on the amount of operation you need to call over your table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the union

```
$questions = DB::table('questions');
$challenges = DB::table('challenges');

return $questions->union($challenges)->paginate(15);
```

You can add some additional constraints or order by on the query that **union()** returns and before calling **paginate()**

If the arrays have different number of columns you can list the common ones that need to be fetched:

```
$questions = DB::table('questions')->select('column1', 'column2');
$challenges = DB::table('challenges')->select('column1', 'column2');

return $questions->union($challenges)->paginate(15);
```

Comment: columns are different for challenges and questions.

Comment: shows error : --   Cardinality violation: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: You can list the columns that will be fetched by adding a call to ->select(['column1', 'column2']) to work around the cardinality error.

Comment: iam new to laravel can u plz explain with sample code?